# How do I register logging driver for docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm trying to use Amazon CloudWatch Logs logging driver as described in [this doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/logging/awslogs/).

But I get following error when I launch my container

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 1769b857d0ed51cf30b1c160485c9eb05f68ab07a84eaf861893d9d55e6139c4: 
Failed to initialize logging driver: 
Failed to get logging factory: logger: no log driver named 'awslogs' is registered
```

How do I register driver for docker ? Shall I modify docker's systemd script or something ?

Answer (score 0):

I posted bug on docker's github and got a reply that awslogs was not added until 1.9.0.